# Query with multiple uri's

Tags: android, cursor, uri, contactscontract

```
Uri contactUri1 = Uri.withAppendedPath(
    ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(number1));
Cursor phones = getContentResolver()
    .query(contactUri1, PEOPLE_PROJECTION, null, null, null);
```

This works. I can get what I need in the cursor given number1.

What I want is to query for multiple numbers and get all the results in the same cursor.

EXAMPLE:

```
Uri contactUri1 = ...
Uri contactUri2 = ...
Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(...  //Both URI's
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Did you take a look at MergeCursor - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/MergeCursor.html?

Comment: Suppose that will do it. Thanks.